# Debug Packet Loss In TCP Communication in iOS/iPad Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, tcp, gcdasyncsocket, cfsocket

I have an iOS application that remotely connects to 3 sockets(of some hardware). Each Socket has its own priority. One channel is only used for transferring messages between iPad App & hardware, one for Tx/Rx Images, another one for Tx/Rx Videos. I had implemented all the three sockets using [GCDAsyncSocket API](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) & things worked fine while using MSGSocket/ImageSocket (OR) MSGSocket/VideoSocket, but when I start using the VideoSocket/ImageSocket/MSGSocket simultaneously this is where things go a little haywire. **I Lose Packets of Data.{Actually a chunk of file goes missing :-(}** I went through the API & found some bug in the API: [Unable to complete Read Stream](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket/issues/89) which I assumed could be a cause of problem. Hence, I Switched to threads & implemented the same using NSThreads/CFSocket API.

I changed only the implementation for ImageSocket/VideoSocket code using NSThreads/CFSocket API & here is the implementation of the same [dropbox-ed](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zr6uztia8njt1e5/Sockets_implementaion.zip?dl=0). I'm just unable to understand as to where the things are going wrong whether it is at iOS App end or at the Server side. In my understanding there shall be no loss of packets in TCP Communication.

Is there a way to Debug This issue. Also I request to go through the code & let me know if any thing is wrong(I know this can be too much that I'm asking for but I need some assurance as to the code implementation is correct). Any help to resolve this issue will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT 1:** After @JoeMcMahon Comment, I referred to this [Technical Q&A](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1176/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10001707-CH1-SECIOSPACKETTRACING) & got a [TCP Dump - trace.pcap file](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=B80F9933B9E58621%21106). I opened this tcp dump with Wireshark & it does show me the bytes transferred between the ports of hardware & iPad.
Also in the terminal when I stopped the tcp dump capture I saw these messages:
12463 packets captured
36469 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
Can someone point out the difference between packets captured & packets received by filter?
**Note -** The TCP dump attached is not for a failed scenario.
*EDIT 1.1:* Found the answer to difference between packets captured & packets received by filter [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29367/tcpdump-packets-captured-vs-packets-received-by-filter)

Comment: I'm assuming you've Wiresharked this so you can see what the actual traffic is - if you haven't that might be enlightening.

Comment: Your issue is not packet loss. You are working with TCP stream sockets, which are totally unaware of any packets. The operating system takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

TCP communication is not guaranteed to be reliable. The basic ack-syn paradigm can break, that is why you have re-transmission mechanism etc. Wireshark reports such problem in your packet capture session.

For using wireshark/tcpdump, you generally want to provide a filter, since the amount of traffic goes through the wire is overwhelming (ping, ntp, etc), you want to filter the capture using some basic filter to see the packets which is relevant to you. The packets which are filtered out is not captured, hence the numerical difference.

If it is a chunk of file went missing, I doubt issue is at TCP level. Most likely it is something higher level went wrong. I would run a fixed size file repeatedly through the channel till I can reliably reproduce the loss.

Comment: TCP communication IS guaranteed to be reliable, per the RFC793 spec at [https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt), page 3. IP is what may not be reliable.